# Regex Expression written

Tags: regex

i want to extract the length which is highlighte bold in the text below in Regex expression. Is there anyone here, who can help me? Please

> u01200.037.0225 3/8 **2.1/4** 25 + normen asme b18.2.1 bs ≈1768 sechskantschrauben unc asme b18.2.1 stahl
> u01200.037.0200 3/8 **2 inch** 25 + normen asme b18.2.1 bs ≈1768 sechskantschrauben unc asme b18.2.1 stahl
> u01200.037.0475 3/8 **3/4** 10 + normen asme b18.2.1 bs ≈1768 sechskantschrauben unc asme b18.2.1
> 04400.160.030 m16 **30.0** preis anzeigen 50 + normen din ≈6921 ripp
> fnlu1100095 d931 a2 6k schraube lubo m10x**95**/

I have tried to writte it like that:

```
.*d+[:|,]?\s?[a-z][0-9]|[\/][0-9]|x\s?(\d+[1-9]\s?.{0}*).*
```

Comment: try your regex with [regex101](https://regex101.com/), you'll see that there is an error.

Comment: Why not the other numbers?

Comment: Can you provide more examples?

Answer (score 0):

For the first 3 examples, you can use the following.

```
\.\d{4} +\d+\/\d+ +(.+?) +\d+
```

Output, for group 1.

```
2.1/4
2 inch
3/4
```

And, for the last example, you can use the following.
If you have more examples of this one, I might be able to refine the pattern.

Right now it's leveraging the *"m"* and *"x"* characters to get the last value.

```
\.\d{3}.+?(\d+\.\d+).+?m\d+x(\d+)
```

Output, for group 1 and 2.

```
30.0
95
```

You can combine these two patterns with |, and then, from within your program, derive a group 1, or a group 2 and 3, depending on the text.

```
\.\d{4} +\d+\/\d+ +(.+?) +\d+|\.\d{3}.+?(\d+\.\d+).+?m\d+x(\d+)
```

Comment: Hi @Reilas, thank you for your reply. I performed the differents codes. By the first code, the pattern doesn't match. The symbol / \ is for fraction numbers right? the Regex has marked it as an error.

Comment: @Angy, which regex engine are you using?  The PCRE?  I was using the Java engine.  I'll re-write the answer.  You can just escape that value with \, and it should work

Comment: Hi @Reilas, yes i am using Regex PCRE and at the End,  i want to match this pattern in Kniwe. The pattern unfortunately doesn't work.

Comment: @Angy, I've updated the answer.  I am unsure why it wouldn't work, it matches correctly here.  You're saying it's in a different language?  Possibly that is the reason.  I believe _\d_ is going to match _0-9_, so possibly there are different numbers within that language.